# Read lines from a text file and store it in a multi-dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, readfile

G'day,

So I've been trying to read some line from a .txt file and store it a multi-dimensional array.

The text file looks like this -

```
 John, BOL12345
 Mary2, BOL77777
 Anna, BOL54321
```

And this is my code -

```
 <?php

 $fileUsername = array();
 $filePassword = array();

 $myFile = "../../data/manager.txt";

 $openFile = fopen($myFile, "r");

  if (file_exists($myFile))
  {
     while (!feof($openFile))
     { 
       $login = fgets($openFile);

       $fileUsername = explode(", ", $login);
       $filePassword = explode(" ", $login);

       echo $fileUsername[0];
       echo $filePassword[1];
       echo "<br>"; 
     }

      fclose($openFile);
  }
  else
  {
    echo "File doesn't exists!";
  } 

  ?>
```

What I want to do is read the file and store the values like this -

```
$fileUsername = [John,Mary2,Anna];
$filePassword = [BOL12345,BOL77777,BOL54321];
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I sure hope you're using this for "internal" purposes; scary.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "internal"?

Comment: As in "Intranet" and not "Internet". Unless you have an **"iron clad"** method of preventing someone from easily figuring out usernames and passwords stored in a plain text file and no counter-measures against injection, wow. Use a database.

Comment: It's a part of my tutorial. I can, and have used a database but that's not what my teacher wants :(

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then. Just as long as your teacher isn't planning on you to use it for future use ;-)

Comment: You're new here and welcome to SO. Now that you've found a solution, the way things are done around here is, when someone gives you an answer that solved your problem, there's a little white checkmark next to the answer and once you click on it, it will turn GREEN. That gives rep points to the person who helped you out.

Comment: Lol. Yeah. Thanks for the concern though :)

Comment: I tried doing that but don't have enough reputation, unfortunately.

Comment: I think you tried to click the UP arrow; that yes, you need more rep points for that. You need to click the checkmark underneath the arrows.

Comment: Oh ohk. I didn't know I could click on the arrow. Done. :)

Comment: And now... you know :-) well done, cheers. And by doing that, it earned you 2 rep points at the same time.

Comment: This website is great! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use [`file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function

```
if (file_exists($myFile))
{
     $fileContent = file($myFile);

     foreach($fileContent as $line_num => $line) {
     { 
       $data = explode(", ", $line);

       $fileUsername[] = trim($data[0]);
       $filePassword[] = trim($data[1]);
     }
}
```

Comment: @user1817460 Click the white checkmark to the left till it turns green. It's a way to show "thanks".

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [serialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead?

Comment: Thanks for replying to the question, Machavity. No, I didn't. I'm still a beginner and didn't even know about it :(